# A non-admin user claims she was able to edit a record which is programmatically locked but now she cannot

Tags: apex, aura, approval-process, locking

As far as I know a programmatically locked record can only be edited by an admin user and current situation seems normal to me.

**Note**: Locking is also done from a component she uses.

This is the only line related with locking in component's controller.

```
Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(recordList, false);
```

**Question**: In what ways can I make her user be able to edit those records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, one does not need to be an "Admin". Modify All on the Object level is enough. This can be granted with any permission set.